# Will the .lower function in an if statement interrupt the correct input?

Tags: python, if-statement

Python3 noob here. In the below code I expect if I enter "window" for the choice1 input then it would move on to the input prompt for choice2. But what I get instead is the else statement at the bottom, "You fell into a spike pit as you entered the house! Game Over." What am I doing wrong? Thanks

````
choice1 = input('You are in front of the house, which way do you want to enter? Type "front door" or "window" and hit Enter \n')
if choice1.lower == "window":
    choice2 = input('You snuck in through a window. You come to the foyer and can take the staircase upstairs or down to the basement. Type "basement" or "upstairs" and hit Enter to proceed \n')
    if choice2.lower == "upstairs":
        choice3 = input("You go upstairs and are in a hallway with 3 doors to enter: 1 red, 1 green, 1 blue. Which color door do you choose? \n")
        if choice3.lower == "red":
            print("The room is full of poisonous snakes! Game over.")
        elif choice3.lower == "green":
            print("You found the lost trick-or-treaters and lead them out of the haunted house to safety. You win!")
        elif choice3.lower == "blue":
            print("You ended up in a warewolf's room. It eats you! Game over.")
        else:
            print("This door doesn't exist... Game over.")
    else:
        print("You encountered a witch who cast a spell turning you into a rat! Game Over.")
else:
    print("You fell into a spike pit as you entered the house! Game Over.")```
````

Comment: It should be `lower()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lower is a method, so you need to use choice1.lower() instead of choice1.lower. choice1.lower will give you the method object instead of a string which you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm noticing you did [variable].lower, variable being a placeholder for whatever variable you used.

You are accessing the function object itself, not the actual function to run, if you want to run the function, you need to change everything to [variable].lower() -- like this:

````py
choice1 = input('You are in front of the house, which way do you want to enter? Type "front door" or "window" and hit Enter \n')
if choice1.lower() == "window":
    choice2 = input('You snuck in through a window. You come to the foyer and can take the staircase upstairs or down to the basement. Type "basement" or "upstairs" and hit Enter to proceed \n')
    if choice2.lower() == "upstairs":
        choice3 = input("You go upstairs and are in a hallway with 3 doors to enter: 1 red, 1 green, 1 blue. Which color door do you choose? \n")
        if choice3.lower() == "red":
            print("The room is full of poisonous snakes! Game over.")
        elif choice3.lower() == "green":
            print("You found the lost trick-or-treaters and lead them out of the haunted house to safety. You win!")
        elif choice3.lower() == "blue":
            print("You ended up in a warewolf's room. It eats you! Game over.")
        else:
            print("This door doesn't exist... Game over.")
    else:
        print("You encountered a witch who cast a spell turning you into a rat! Game Over.")
else:
    print("You fell into a spike pit as you entered the house! Game Over.")```
````

Answer (score 1):

You need to add parenthesis to your `.lower` method. Like this - `choice1.lower()` Without them the method would not be called. And that is why you get the error because `.lower` will give out the memory location. So use Parenthesis for `.lower()`